# win32 atoi issue which can't convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t [5]' to 'const char *

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to convert from string to integer, so I used atoi() in winapi as the below.
when I use atoi function, I came across with this error message

```
1>d:\work\usb\isp1\isp1\source1.cpp(771): error C2664: 'int atoi(const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t [5]' to 'const char *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

How do I convert string to integer ?

```
HWND hEdit_a;
HWND hEdit_d;
wchar_t str_a[5];
wchar_t str_d[5];

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{


    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static HANDLE hTimer;
    switch (iMessage)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

case ID_EDIT_A:
        switch (HIWORD(wParam)) {
        case EN_CHANGE:
            GetWindowText(hEdit_a, str_a, 5);
            //SetWindowText(hWnd, str_a);
        }
        break;

....
case 4: //single i2c write
            int ii;
            int iii;
            ii = atoi(str_a);
            iii = atoi(str_d);

            write_i2c()
            break;
```

Comment: Why on earth are you calling this function in the first place? Why don't you use the idiomatic way to convert text to integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi` is for `const char *` strings; what you have is a `wchar_t` string. `char` and `wchar_t` are not interchangeable. Use the corresponding function for `wchar_t` strings; [`_wtoi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx):

```
ii = _wtoi(str_a);
iii = _wtoi(str_d);
```

Comment: Thanks but I've got the below error message 1>d:\work\usb\isp1\isp1\source1.cpp(771): error C3861: 'wtoi': identifier not found

Comment: `_wtoi` not `wtoi`

Comment: @foe1 That may be best to ask in a new question.

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:c++], a better solution would be [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). The most important improvement over the `atoi` family of functions is proper error reporting.